# Branding mobile app/webpage

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have read a little bit about Power BI and it looks like a great tool. I need to provide reports/dashboard in the way that client would see my branding, is it possible? It looks like it works for webpages as you can use the embedded power bi functionality, but what with mobile bi experience. Let's say with the power bi app, is there a way to creat a clone of this application with your own branding and different name (rather than power bi app)? If it doesn't work can i somehow use PowerApps? Can I create my own let's say iphone app using PowerApps which shows reports/dashboards? How does it work with regards to security, can I have 2 factor authentication?

The more complicated scenerio which I really would like to achieve is to a webpage which has 2 pages, one with embedded Power BI and another one with SSRS reports. What is the best way to achieve that? It would be great if a user needs to login to the page only once?

I would appreciate your indications what is possible and what not and how current companies deal with such issues.

Regards,
Rafal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is Power BI Embedded. As you say, it allows you to embed Power BI reports into externally facing mobile apps or websites. More information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded/

To complete your more complicated scenario, you can use the Report Viewer control to embed SSRS reports into a website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337090.aspx. In terms of logging in, both Power BI Embedded & Report Viewer allow your application to authenticate behind the scenes against their respective services. End user security is left to your app/website to handle.

Re-branding the existing Power BI mobile app is a no-go. It comes as-is.

Power Apps can be used to collect data that is then loaded into Power BI, but I've never heard of Power BI tiles/reports being embedded into a Power App.

All these technologies are rapidly evolving, though. What's true today could easily change as features are added & feedback is received.

Comment: Thanks Leonard, it is what i thought, just wanted to have it confirmed. Let's see how it improves.